# Where does MongoDB store function added via console?

Tags: mongodb, console, performancecounter

I created auto-incrementing sequence field via counters collection and `getNextSequence()` function (absolutely like in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/))

According [another document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) JavaScript functions are stored in a special system collection named `system.js`

But there is no such collection at my database (a least `db.system.js.find()` shows empty result):

```
> db.dropDatabase();
{ "dropped" : "mongopa", "ok" : 1 }
> version()
3.2.5
> db.counters.insert({_id: "userid", seq: 0 })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.counters.find()
{ "_id" : "userid", "seq" : 0 }
> function getNextSequence(name) {
...    var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
...           {
...             query: { _id: name },
...             update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
...             new: true
...           }
...    );
... 
...    return ret.seq;
... }
> db.system.js.find()
> show collections
counters
> db.users.insert({"login":"demo","user_id":getNextSequence("userid"),"password":"demo"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("574ff1c7436a1b4f9c6f47b9"), "login" : "demo", "user_id" : 1, "password" : "demo" }
> db.users.insert({"login":"demo2","user_id":getNextSequence("userid"),"password":"demo2"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("574ff1c7436a1b4f9c6f47b9"), "login" : "demo", "user_id" : 1, "password" : "demo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("574ff1d6436a1b4f9c6f47ba"), "login" : "demo2", "user_id" : 2, "password" : "demo2" }
>
```

So where does the getNextSequence function really stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the function as,

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
       {
             query: { _id: name },
         update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
         new: true
       }
);
return ret.seq;
}
```

It is merely defined for that particular session and is not available to you once the session ends. Hence, its not saved anywhere.

To make the function re-usable across the sessions, you need to explicitly save the function is system.js by using,

```
db.system.js.save(
{
    _id: "getNextSequence",
    value: function(name){var ret = db.counters.findAndModify({
             query: { _id: name },
             update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
             new: true
       });
    return ret.seq;}
 })
```

Once you have saved the function, you can cross-check it by,

```
db.system.js.find()
```

You need to call this

> db.loadServerScripts();

across the sessions. It loads all the scripts saved in *system.js* collection.

For details, please check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/).